# Defining partial or complete overlap with QgsSpatialIndex

Tags: pyqgis, intersection, spatial-index

I'm working on adding some functionality to a QGIS plugin. It currently uses a `QgsSpatialIndex` to efficiently compute whether the features of a vector layer intersect (potentially millions) of QgsRectangles representing tile bounds. This is reasonably straightforward:

```py
spatialIndex = QgsSpatialIndex()
canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
geomTransform = QgsCoordinateTransform(canvas.mapRenderer().destinationCrs(),\
                QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'))
# layer is a QgsVectorLayer, from a combobox selection
vals = {feature.id(): feature for (Feature) in layer.getFeatures()}.values()
for v in vals:
    v.geometry().transform(geomTransform)
map(spatialIndex.insertFeature, vals)
```

Then later I can check whether a given `QgsRectangle` intersects features participating in this index:

```py
# includes pseudo-code
if spatialIndex.intersects(rectangle):
    # Feature intersects the rectangle
    # Both partial and complete overlaps are included
    if complete_overlap:
        render_one_way()
    elif partial_overlap:
        render_another_way()
else:
    # No features intersect the rectangle
    dont_render()
```

[This is very fast](http://nathanw.net/2013/01/04/using-a-qgis-spatial-index-to-speed-up-your-code/). However, I need to be able to distinguish between `QgsRectangle` objects that intersect features in the spatial index *partially*, and those that overlap *completely*. The [`QgsSpatialIndex.intersects`](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsSpatialIndex.html#a7ba7938334e2e9a3cacb70e01f529707) method only tells me if there is any kind of intersection.

**How can I efficiently determine whether it is a partial or complete overlap?**

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your aim? Why are you interested in partially overlapping bounding boxes?

Comment: Conditional rendering of tiles. I am producing a cache of land tiles that are transparent over land, and opaque over the sea. These tiles' alpha channels then get inserted during the rendering of other tiles (my own tile server), as a fast way of masking land for oceanic phenomena. The best way to do *that* is to have oceanic tiles as 0 byte files, and full-land tiles as 1 byte files, so then I can just use `os.stat` to work out if a mask should be fully opaque or fully transparent without opening the tile image. So the only tiles I really need to render are on the coast: a partial overlap.

Comment: The first-pass intersection is already useful generally (https://github.com/nextgis/QTiles/pull/59), but I want this additional step to make rendering even faster for my own purposes. I need up to zoom level 18, so the only way to make this tractable with a static tile cache is to dramatically reduce the number of tiles that need to be rendered in QGIS.

Comment: That makes sense. I can't say right away how to do it without materializing the spatial index by writing the bounding boxes as polygons into a separate table.

Comment: Can you get MinX, MinY, MaxX and MaxY out of the object of the spatial index? if you can you could make your own query: If both minx and maxx of the feature are between the minx and maxx of the index object, and the same for the y coordinates, the feature is totally inside.

Comment: A another idea would be to check if a geometry contains another one, but you have to use QgsGemometry.contains(QgsGeometry). First check for those instersect and then check if a geometry contains another (but only for those intersect one another) dont check for every geometry that's in your intersect list.